# Как получить все возможные координаты?

Tags: javascript, node.js

Как я могу получить список всех возможных комбинаций координат?

```
const vec3 = require('vec3')

var min = vec3(0,0,0)
var max = vec3(3,3,3)
```

на выходе должно получится: [ [0,0,0], [1,0,0], [2,0,0], [3,0,0], [0,1,0], [0,2,0], [0,3,0] и т.д ... ]

нигде не нашел как это можно сделать

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
const allVariants = (min, max) => {

    const variants = [];

    for(let x = min[0]; x <= max[0]; x++) {
        for(let y = min[1]; y <= max[1]; y++) {
            for(let z = min[2]; z <= max[2]; z++) {
                variants.push(vec3(x,y,z))
            }
        }
    }

    return variants;
}
```